# Changing the value of the XML element

Tags: c#, xml, rest, asp.net-web-api, xml-parsing

I am calling a third party API from the Rest AP I am creating. The third party API always returns in XML and it looks like

```
  <prj:prj uri="https://bh.org/api/v2/prj/V51" lid="V51" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:file="http://ge.com/ri/file" xmlns:prj="http://ge.com/ri/prj">
  <name>fgfgfg</name>
  <res uri="https://bh.org/api/v2/res/19"/>
  <udf:type name="cis"/>
  <udf:field type="String" name="ST">Cli</udf:field>
  <udf:field type="String" name="CPN">TestName</udf:field>
  <udf:field type="Numeric" name="No">1</udf:field>
  <udf:field type="String" name="CA">Do not know</udf:field>
  <udf:field type="String" name="Cto">Me</udf:field>
  <udf:field type="String" name="Site">GT</udf:field>
  </prj:prj>
```

I should change the `name` from `fgfgfg` to `ABCD`. I am trying to get the response in the XDocument

```
  var new_Name = "ABCD";
  string responseString = response_LabURL.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  XDocument new_doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString_LabURL);
```

Now here I am not sure how to change the

```
<name>fgfgfg</name>
```

into

```
 <name>ABCD</name>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = new_doc.Elements("name").Single();
element.Value = new_Name;
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @Nonik It didnt work but throws error `ExceptionMessage":"Sequence contains no elements","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource]`

Comment: Yes, I don't know name of the element you are trying to change, change "name" to the element name you are trying to change and always check if element variable is not null